# WHERE statement not functioning

Tags: mariadb

I am attempting to filter the accountledger.transactiondate to only return those refunds between 2019-04-01 and 2020-03-31.

However WHERE clause is ineffective.

I have repositioned the WHERE statement to many locations within the script; with no change in results.

This is my code:

```
SELECT accountledger.CAMPUSCODE, accountledger.ID, students.FNAME,
    students.LNAME, accountledger.PROGRAM,
    accountledger.TRANSACTIONDATE, accountledger.TRANSACTIONAMOUNT,
    accountledger.DESCRIPTION as 'ENR Desc',
    accountledger.TRANSACTIONCODE as 'Inv Desc',
    chart_accounts.NAME AS 'ChAcc Name' 
FROM accountledger 

INNER JOIN students 
  ON accountledger.ID = students.ID
INNER JOIN fees 
  ON accountledger.TRANSACTIONCODE = fees.NAME
INNER JOIN chart_accounts 
  ON fees.ACCOUNT = chart_accounts.ACCOUNT

WHERE accountledger.TRANSACTIONtype = 'I' 
  and accountledger.transactioncode like '%refund%'
   or accountledger.transactioncode like '%paid to d-ed%'
   or accountledger.transactioncode like '%paid to military%'
   or accountledger.transactioncode like '%paid to voc rehab%'
  and chart_accounts.NAME
  AND accountledger.transactiondate BETWEEN 2019-04-01 AND 2020-03-31
GROUP BY accountledger.id
ORDER BY accountledger.TRANSACTIONDATE
```

I am expecting only those refund issued within the date parameters of the WHERE statement.  However, the script returns all refunds, regardless of transaction date.

Comment: You might need to wrap your or clauses in parenthesis

Comment: You _do_ need parens.  `x AND y OR z` means `(x AND y) OR z`, but you want `x AND (y OR z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct syntax

```
accountledger.transactiondate BETWEEN CAST('2019-04-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2020-03-31' AS DATE)
```

instead of

```
accountledger.transactiondate BETWEEN 2019-04-01 AND 2020-03-31
```

Comment: The `CAST` is overkill -- all that is needed is the quotes:  `... BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31'`